# how to run .drone.yml in windows runner server

Tags: c#, drone.io

drone.yml for my project (C# - .net framework).my runner server is windows but i can run .drone.pipeline in server and get error permission denied.(my project (c# -.net core) is worked on linux runner server).i can't run project on linux runner server because i use .net framework

my drone file is:

```
 kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: default

steps:
  - name: en
    image: alpine
    commands:
    - echo hello
    - echo world
    
  - name: fr
    image: alpine
    commands:
    - echo bounjour
    - echo monde
    when:
      ref:
        include:
        - refs/heads/feature-*
        exclude:
        - refs/heads/**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for windows runner you must use a platform in your drone file like this code :

```
platform:
  os: windows
  arch: amd64
```

this link maybe helps you(sample) :
[.drone.yml](https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/master/.drone.yml)